# JS to pass the indexes from 1 to 1 on the same page

Tags: javascript

I need help, I'm blocking because I'd like to pass the index 1 of the table to 0 and the index 2 to 1 so on (index 2 to 0, index 3 to 1) to browse a table at the next button ... how to do? thank you

```
 var i=1;
 this.current.valItems.forEach((value, key) => {
   if (value==i) {
     this.current.afficheItems[value]=this.current.afficheItems[key]="0";
   } else {
     this.current.afficheItems[value]="1";
   }                 
 });
```

Comment: english please!

Comment: please add the object as well ...

Comment: "Translated using google" :D

Comment: sorry i can not edit :(

Comment: hello, I need help, I'm blocking because I'd like to pass the index 1 of the table to 0 and the index 2 to 1 so on (index 2 to 0, index 3 to 1) to browse a table at the next button ... how to do? thank you

Comment: I added another answer since the comments were way too many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach:

```js
var afficheItems = ["1", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
var key;
console.log("Before: " + afficheItems);

for(key = 0; key < afficheItems.length; key++)  {
    if(afficheItems[key]=="1" && key < afficheItems.length - 1){
        afficheItems[key]="0";
        afficheItems[key+1]="1";
        break;
    }            
}
console.log("After: " + afficheItems);
```

Comment: Great !!!! It works well ! frankly thank you very much ^^ you have discord?

Comment: You are welcome, in the end I understood what you wanted :P, no I don't